Notching half of an existing 6x6 post
I have a pole barn with 6x6 posts that I’m adding onto the gable end. With my addition I’m using 3 ply lvl beams as truss carriers to get a 15 foot span, where my existing building uses 2 ply 2x10 truss carriers. I need to notch half the 6x6 posts where the lvl headers will mount due to the 3 vs 2 ply and the extra thickness of lvl. The tricky part is when I cut the notches I’ll be in a really confined space with the existing truss carriers and trusses still mounted to the post. I don’t think I’ll be able to get a circular saw in there, so I’m looking for other suggestions on most efficient ways to notch the post. I thought about using a sonicrafter but I’m worried about accuracy trying to use that. Any suggestions? I can try to add a sketch if it’s hard to visualize.
Some sketches to visualize have been added.



A sketch would help.

Added above, thank you.

Any saw that will fit should work.  Hand saws usually need less space.  Accurate cuts depend on taking care and checking measurements/marking lines and using a sharp blade.

If worried about accuracy, take out wood in stages; that means more operations but gives you the chance to fine-tune as you go.
